# How to convert <br> tag to a comma/new column when scraping website with python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the website below. I can get all of the data I need off of it by using the code below. However, **the 'br' tags are creating issues for me. I'd prefer for them to be treated as an indicator for a new column in my data frame.**

Here is the website: [`directory.ccnecommunity.org/...`](https://directory.ccnecommunity.org/reports/rptAccreditedPrograms_New.asp?state=AL&sFullName=Alabama&sProgramType=1)

- I tried BeautifulSoup and got invalid tags. It didn't work too well.
- My thought was to remove every tag except 'br' and then go back and replace them with commas. There was too much other crap that was added and not just the plain text.

Code:

```
url = 'http://directory.ccnecommunity.org/reports/rptAccreditedPrograms_New.asp?state=AL&sFullName=Alabama&sProgramType=1'
table = pd.read_html(url)
table = pd.concat(table[1:-1])
table.columns = table.iloc[0]
table = table.iloc[1:-1]
print(table)
```

I want each indentation in the tables/school section to be a new column in my data frame. I can deal with naming them and cleaning it later. I'm using selenium to get the URLs because the the search page is java script. Would using selenium to do this be better? I can always export to csv and read it back in using pandas. Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Wow, that page has some reaaally broken HTML.  Have a look at [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for walking through the DOM tree.  As it stands, I think your question is too broad.

Comment: It's a headache for sure. I'm working on using BeautifulSoup, but I've got the best results with pandas. Could you explain what you mean by saying my question is too broad? @BradSolomon

Comment: @BradSolomon: this is a good on-topic question, and lots of real-world HTML is dirty, messy, broken, malformed/nested tags, has idiosyncratic format that won't read cleanly with `pd.read_html` without some massaging first. Asking how to parse it without writing lots of ad-hoc code is a very relevant question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re


url = 'http://directory.ccnecommunity.org/reports/rptAccreditedPrograms_New.asp?state=AL&sFullName=Alabama&sProgramType=1'

page_html = requests.get(url).text
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")
tables  = page_soup.find_all("table", id = "finder")

reformattable = []
reg = re.compile(r"(<[\/]?br[\/]?>)+")
for table in tables:
    reformattable.append(re.sub(reg, "<td>", str(table)))

dflist = []
for table in reformattable:
    dflist.append(pd.read_html(str(table)))

info = [dflist[i][0] for i in np.arange(len(dflist))]
stats = [dflist[i][1] for i in np.arange(len(dflist))]

adjInfo = []
for df in info:
    adjInfo.append(pd.concat([df[i] for i in np.arange(len(df.columns))]).dropna().reset_index(drop = True))

adjStats= []
for df in stats:
    df.drop(columns = 1, inplace = True)
    df.dropna(inplace = True)
    df[3] = df[0]+' ' + df[2]
    adjStats.append(df[3])

combo = []
for p1,p2 in zip(adjInfo, adjStats):
    combo.append(pd.concat([p1,p2]))

finaldf = pd.concat([combo[i] for i in np.arange(len(combo))], axis = 1)

finaldf
```

So this gives you exactly what you want. Lets go over it.

After inspecting the website we can see that each section is a "table" with the id of finder. So we looked for this using beautiful soup. Next we had to reformat the `<br>` tags to make it easier to load into a df. So I replaced all the `<br>` tags with a single `<td>` tag.

Another issue with the website was that each section was broken up into 2 tables. So we would have 2 df per one section. In order to make cleaning easier, I broke them down to both the info and stats dataframe lists.

adjInfo and adjStats simply clean the dataframes and put them in a list. Next week recombine information into single columns for each section and put it in combo.

Finally we take all the columns in combo and concat them to get our finaldf.

**EDIT**

To loop:

```
finaldf = pd.DataFrame()
for changeinurl in url:
    #fix it to however you manipulated the url for your loop
    url = 'http://directory.ccnecommunity.org/reports/rptAccreditedPrograms_New.asp?state=AL&sFullName=Alabama&sProgramType=1'

    page_html = requests.get(url).text
    page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")
    tables  = page_soup.find_all("table", id = "finder")

    reformattable = []
    reg = re.compile(r"(<[\/]?br[\/]?>)+")
    for table in tables:
        reformattable.append(re.sub(reg, "<td>", str(table)))

    dflist = []
    for table in reformattable:
        dflist.append(pd.read_html(str(table)))

    info = [dflist[i][0] for i in np.arange(len(dflist))]
    stats = [dflist[i][1] for i in np.arange(len(dflist))]

    adjInfo = []
    for df in info:
        adjInfo.append(pd.concat([df[i] for i in np.arange(len(df.columns))]).dropna().reset_index(drop = True))

    adjStats= []
    for df in stats:
        df.drop(columns = 1, inplace = True)
        df.dropna(inplace = True)
        df[3] = df[0]+' ' + df[2]
        adjStats.append(df[3])

    combo = []
    for p1,p2 in zip(adjInfo, adjStats):
        combo.append(pd.concat([p1,p2]))

    df = pd.concat([combo[i] for i in np.arange(len(combo))], axis = 1).reset_index(drop = True).T

    finaldf.append(df)
```

Comment: Wow! This works. I have another site with a similar set up which I need to scrape so I will use and modify this. I appreciate your efforts!

Comment: I'm trying to run this as a for loop while change the url everytime. However, I'm getting an Invalid Index Error when I try and concat the finaldf. Is there a way to transpose the data frames before combining them? That way I would have the index be the school name and they would be the start of each row.

Comment: Edited to show how you would loop, and transposed the data so that the school name will be the first column.